# Why we need more than 3 master cluster for kubernetes HA

Tags: kubernetes

I see most of the K8S master components has a leader selection process except apiServer. If only one node will be the leader any point of time, why would we need more then 3 master cluster for bigger k8s cluster?

Answer (score 1):

The requirement of minimum 3 hosts comes from the fact that Kubernetes HA cluster uses etcd for storing and syncing configuration. etcd requires minimum 3 nodes to ensure HA. In general case we need to use n+1 model when want to deploy Kubernetes HA cluster

In a single master setup, the master node manages the etcd database, API server, controller manager and scheduler, along with the worker nodes. However, if that single master node fails, all the worker node fail as well and entire cluster will be lost.
In a multi-master setup, by contrast, multi-master provides high availability for a single cluster and improves network performance because all the masters behave like a unified data center.
A multi-master setup protects against a wide range of failure modes, from a loss of single worker node to the failure of the master node’s etcd service. By providing redundancy, a multi-master cluster serves a highly available system for your end users.

Do not use a cluster with two master replicas. Consensus on a two-replica cluster requires both replicas running when changing persistent state. As a result, both replicas are needed and a failure of any replica turns cluster into majority failure state. A two-replica cluster is thus inferior, in terms of HA, to a single replica cluster.

Here are useful documentation: [kubernetes-ha-cluster](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/highly-available-master/), [creating-ha-cluster](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/high-availability/).

Articles: [ha-cluster](https://www.akamenskiy.com/deploy-kubernetes-ha-cluster/), [ha](https://thenewstack.io/kubernetes-high-availability-no-single-point-of-failure/).

Comment: Thanks, MaggieO for your reply. I was not expecting this answer. I know the minimum 3 node master cluster need for full HA solution. But my question was, if you have 5000 worker node cluster, you may need 2n+1 (suppose in this case n=5) master node cluster. Why we have to go beyond 3 node master cluster in this case? if one master node will be the leader at any particular point of time? Does this make my question clear?

Comment: Are you talking about any specific implementation? Depending on the number of nodes, K8s determines the size of the master machine, not the number of masters. For HA, the number of master is determined by the number of geographical locations providing redundancy and, based on that, there are actual [leader election algorithms](https://git.io/fjjkU) in the masters. Now, leader election is a common strategy for distributed systems to break symmetry and to serve as a centralized controller for that decentralized system.

Comment: @Malgorzata, do you mean, "etcd requires minimum 3 nodes to ensure HA" that is why kubernetes needs 3 master nodes?